# REGEX in vim search & replace (VS Code + macbook) not working?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, search, vim-plugin

I'm trying to edit a .md file in VS Code and I want to replace every tag starting with `#+END_...` with a space character (or just nothing). This is in VS Code 1.80.1 with the Vim extension installed, on Macbook Big Sur.

I've tried these:

```
10,20s/#+END\(.*\)\n//g
10,20s/#+END\(.*\)//g
10,20s/#+END\{.*\}\n//g
```

but every time VS Code says it doesn't find the pattern. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to tweak any particular config of the VIM extension in VS Code?

(*I'm a bit new to VS Code, please help*)

Here's a snippet of the text I'm trying to replace

[image]

### EDIT 1

[image: vs-code's VIM setting for RegEx]

Comment: can any kind Samaritan post their entry for the VIM setting: `vim.easymotionJumpToAnywhereRegex`, please? Perhaps that's what's not working... Meanwhile I've installed `neovim` and the same search & replace regex pattern in the OP works just fine.

Comment: Did you try `10,20s/#\+END_.*//`

Comment: @Thefourthbird , just tried a search and replace pattern (on another file) with the `.*` as you suggested -- WORKS! Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
10,20s/#\+END_.*//
```

**Explanation**

- `10,20` Range, for line 10-20
- `s/` Start substitution
- `#\+END_` Match `#+END_`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `//` Substitute with an empty string